# Java generic operators

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method:

```
  private <E extends Number> double GetAverage(ArrayList<E> al)
  {
    double total = 0;
    Iterator<E> itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
      total += itr.next();
    }

    return total;
  }
```

but it does not compile. I get a

> "total cannot be resolved or is not a field"

on line

> "total += itr.next();"

I understand that Java doesn't know the value of E, but I hope you understand what I mean, what is the best way to create a generic method that adds the total(Numeric values) of an ArrayList.

Comment: What's `retVal` in your example? Did you mean `total`? Do you use any IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually syntax errors with your code, you have line that's not complete. Your full code should be:

```
private <E extends Number> double GetAverage(ArrayList<E> al) {
    double total = 0;
    Iterator<E> itr = al.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        E next = itr.next();
        total += next.doubleValue();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Note: the return of 'total' and not undefined retVal

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks like this:

```
itr.next().
total += itr.next();
```

Which the compiler is reading as this:

```
itr.next().total += itr.next();
```

The compiler is suggesting that there is no field named `total` that is accessible on `Number`.  You probably meant to not have this line:

```
itr.next().
```

On another note, I am not sure that `Number` will auto-unbox into a `double`.  You may need to call [`Number#doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) on the `Number` instance.

```
total += itr.next().doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a generic `Number` to a `double`.  There's no way to store `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` inside a `double` field, so addition is just not definable on (`double` ⨯ `Number`).

Try

```
total += itr.next().doubleValue();
```

if you can safely assume that the numbers are reducible to `double` without too much loss of precision.

To make your code properly generic, try this:

```
private <E extends Number> double GetAverage(Iterable<E> list)
{
  double total = 0;
  for (E num : list) {
    total += num.doubleValue();
  }
  return total;
}
```

If you want to treat `null` as a NaN value instead of failing with an exception you will have to do that with an `if` inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extraneous line in the code - the first itr.next() line (that ends with a dot).  Also, you can't add a Number, you need to add the doubleValue.  Finally, you need to return total, not retVal.

e.g.

```
 private <E extends Number> double GetAverage(ArrayList<E> al)
   {
     double total = 0;
     Iterator<E> itr = al.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext())
     {
       total += itr.next().doubleValue();
     }

     return total;
   }
```

Since all Numbers have getDouble, you could simplify things by using the new for() iterator.

```
private <E extends Number> double GetAverage(Collection<E> al)
   {
     double total = 0;
     for (Number n : al)
       total += n.doubleValue();

     return total;
   }
```

Depending upon details, you might be able to get rid of the E extends Number stuff and just say Number...

And, definitely change the input parameter from `ArrayList<E>` to `List<E>` or even `Collection<E>`, as I did in the second example.